# Consecutive MySQL queries from Go become MUCH slower after some point

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds

I'm writing a job in go that goes through some MySQL tables, selects some of the rows based on some critera, extracts email addresses from them and sends an email to each.

The filtering process looks at a table (let's call it `storage`) which is pretty big (~6gb dumped) and looks like this:

```
Columns:
id      varchar(64) PK
path    varchar(64) PK
game    varchar(64)
guid    varchar(64)
value   varchar(512)
timestamp   timestamp
```

There are two indices: `(id, path)` (the PK as seen above) and `guid`.

The job first retrieves a long list of guids from one table, then batches them and performs consecutive queries like this on the `storage` table:

```sql
SELECT guid, timestamp FROM storage 
WHERE game = 'somegame' 
AND path = 'path' AND value = 'value' AND timestamp >= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.0' AND timestamp <= '2015-04-29T14:53:07+02:00' 
AND guid IN ( ... )
```

Where the `IN` clause contains a list of guids.

I need to retrieve timestamps to be able to filter further.

**When running against my local MySQL**, everything works as expected, the query takes about 180ms with batches of 1000 guids.

**When running against the same DB on Amazon RDS**, the queries begin quick, but after some point, they suddenly start taking around 30 seconds, and continue to do so until the job ends.

I have tried many many things to fix this, but can't figure out the reason. Some notes:

- The job uses only one `sql.DB` object. Also, I prepare the above statement once and reuse it quite heavily.
- At first, I thought it was because the RDS DB was running MySQL 5.5, and I was running 5.6. I made a replica of the RDS DB, upgraded to 5.6, ran the job again. The problem happened again.
- The volume of data in the two databases is the same: I dumped the production database and imported it into my local database and ran the job. Same behaviour (it still ran quickly locally).
- The AWS monitoring of the RDS nodes doesn't show any significant spikes. The CPU usage jumps from 1% to up to 10%, and the job seems to open just a few connections (~4).
- I had a colleague run the job on their PC, pointing to *my* MySQL DB, just to make sure the great performance didn't stem from the fact that the connection was local. It ran just as quickly as on my PC (admittedly, over LAN).
- I ran the job against RDS *both from my local PC* and from *an Amazon EC2 node*, which is considerably closer to RDS. From EC2, it performed better, but the problem still appeared.
- The job is very concurrent, each step has input and output channels (with buffer sizes of 1000), and the work is performed by goroutines. Between the steps, I have other goroutines that batch the output of the previous goroutine.
- The slowdown is sudden, one query takes milliseconds, and the next one takes tens of seconds.

I haven't the faintest idea why this happens. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm giving away the answer here,  but Amazon is limiting your bandwidth after you run a certain number of queries.  Whether they are actually running each one of your queries more slowly, or only running them at certain intervals, is anyone's guess.

Comment: I can actually answer that, I ran SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST on the DB while the job was running, and  the queries were actually taking longer, they weren't being run at intervals. But how can they make the queries run longer? Also, where can I see that? Is there documentation on the limits and so on?

Comment: Well if the queries are being run in parallel with other tasks then they would appear to take longer.

Comment: I even ran this on a replica that I commissioned precisely for this purpose, it was running no other queries. :-|

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here... Try setting `http://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetMaxIdleConns` to `0`. It sounds like perhaps your connections are stalling out. Eventually they get cleaned up, but in the interim everything is waiting. (https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/257)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lots and lots of experimentation, I found the solution.

I am using Magnetic Storage on the RDS instances involved, which guarantees approximately 100 IOPS. This limited the speed with which we could query the data.

I tested using 2000 [Provisioned IOPS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/), and the job ran quickly all the way.